# Simulate click with setTimeout in Javascript

Tags: javascript, click, settimeout

How would I simulate a click event with setTimeout? Something like:

```
<script>
    window.onload=setTimeout(document.getElementById('mk1').click(),1000);
</script>

<a id="mk1" href="some url">click me</a>
```

Comment: If you really want to simulate a click, then casablanca has the right answer.  If you just want to redirect the page to a different url, then assign a value to window.location

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Currently your code calls `click()` immediately and passes the return value to `setTimeout`. You instead want to pass a function reference to `setTimeout`:

```
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('mk1').click();
  }, 1000);
};
```

**Edit:** As @ThiefMaster points out, you also want to pass a function to `onload`; even though it might seem to work otherwise, it wouldn't do what it really should be doing.

Comment: you need to wrap your call in an anonymous function. right now you assign the setTimeout **return value** to `window.onload`

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Thanks, I entirely overlooked that portion of the code. :)

Comment: "seem to work otherwise": Yes, but it doesn't execute onload but immediately in that case - and it will try to call an integer when onload fires

Comment: @ThiefMaster: True, that's why I said "seem to work" -- since there's a timeout of 1 second and if `onload` fires quickly enough, one might not notice.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById('mk1').click()` is evaluating when the script first runs.  You need to make it into a function and pass that as the first parameter.